# A continuum version of the 1D k-means clustering problem: constant factor approximations

Tags: approximation-algorithms, clustering

Modify the *k*-means clustering problem in 1D by assuming that, instead of a finite number of observations, we must classify into $K$ clusters a continuum of observations, distributed on the unit interval $[0, 1]$ according to some cumulative probability density function $F$. Has this modification been studied?

Here is my specific question: The clustering problem can be reduced to the problem of finding $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{K-1})$ such that the quadratic loss function is minimized? One can characterise these optimal (OPT) thresholds with first-order conditions (which do not admit an explicit solution). One can also think of the intuitive approximation (APX) that would set the thresholds at $a_1=F(1/K), a_2=F(2/K), ..., a_{K-1}=F((K-1)/K))$. One can bound the quadratic loss under APX. (The bound is $1/(4K^2)$.) One could also guess that APX is a constant factor approximation of OPT. Has this approximation been proved?